# How to use blockUI for a specific DIV?

Tags: jquery

How to use blockUI plugin for a particular DIV?
Instead of whole page ?
`$("div.test").blockUI();` Is not working , where test is a class and div is the DIV tag.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple examples of blocking/unblocking elements with [jQuery BlockUI Plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/) (which I assume is what you are using):

```
$('#blockButton').click(function() { 
    $('div.test').block({ message: null }); 
}); 

$('#blockButton2').click(function() { 
    $('div.test').block({ 
        message: '<h1>Processing</h1>', 
        css: { border: '3px solid #a00' } 
    }); 
}); 

$('#unblockButton').click(function() { 
    $('div.test').unblock(); 
});
```

Source: [Element Blocking](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#element)

So for your example:

```
$("div.test").block({ message: 'Navi: Hey! Listen!' });
```

---

**EDIT**

Is this what you are trying to do?

> If you want to use the default settings and have the UI blocked for
>   all ajax requests, it's as easy as this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
```

Comment: I saw those examples .. It wont work ..Because i am not using any button in my program.. When we are calling ajax call that paricular div should get block

Comment: You can call `.block()` from anywhere. In this example, it's called when you click a button, but you can call it before/after your ajax call. If you still need help, set up a short example at JSFiddle.net and post the link here. I'll help you from there.

Comment: No .. I tried .block as follows : $("div.test").block({message:null});But it will not work .. Div is not blocking

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? You are not giving much details, how do you expect us to help you? We can't read your mind (yet..)! ;-) "Blocking a div" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: You figured it out? Cool! Mind to share with us?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.blockUI({ message: $('div#info') }); 
setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000);
```

Try the above code. div#info contains the data you want to show to the user. It will appear for 2 seconds and fade out.

Hope this will help you out. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks